# How can I access property names (not just values) in tpl?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Basically what I'm looking to do is create a view in which an arbitrary JSON object will be rendered into a table, with each row being simply key:value (it's safe to assume that the object contains no nested arrays/objects/etc.).

So for example, if I have an object like:

```
{
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Age": 34
}
```

The usual way to render that in a tpl would be:

```
<td>Name:</td><td>{Name}</td>
<td>Age:</td><td>{Age}</td>
```

However, I want to treat this as if I don't actually know the property names already, so I *want* something like this:

```
<tpl for=".">
    <td>{property.key}</td><td>{property.val}</td>
</tpl>
```

Any idea how this is possible? I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in the docs. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue in future, the solution I came to is actually quite workable, if a little ugly to look at...

Basically, within `{[ ]}` tags you can execute arbitrary code, along with having access to some special variables, such as `values` etc. This may seem limited at first, but if you simply include a self-executing function within these that returns the value you want in your rendered template, you can basically do anything here.

Example:

```
tpl: [
    '<table>',
    '{[ (function() { var output = []; for (i in values) { output.push("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + values[i] + "</td></tr>"); } return output.join(""); }()) ]}',
    '</table>'
]
```

Hope this helps others with the same sort of problem in future!

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution will be

```
    <tpl foreach=".">
       <tr>
        <td>{[xkey]}</td>
        <td>{.}</td>
       </tr>
    </tpl>
```